# Trying to remove punctuation without using regex

Tags: ruby

I am trying to remove punctuation from an array of words without using regular expression. In below eg,

```
str = ["He,llo!"]
```

I want:

```
result # => ["Hello"]
```

I tried:

```
alpha_num="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"
result= str.map do |punc|  
  punc.chars {|ch|alpha_num.include?(ch)}  
end 
p result
```

But it returns `["He,llo!"]` without any change. Can't figure out where the problem is.

Comment: `include?` just checks if the string includes the given character. There is nothing in your code that removes characters.

Comment: You can use `str.gsub(/\W/, ' ')`, the code will be much cleaner.

Comment: @John Baker The OP did say that they didn't want to use regex, although I can't imagine why (perhaps a homework exercise on string manipulation?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
str=["He,llo!"]
alpha_num="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"
```

Program

```
v=[]<<str.map do |x|
  x.chars.map do |c|
    alpha_num.chars.map.include?(c.downcase) ? c : nil
  end
end.flatten.compact.join
```

p v

Output

```
["Hello"]
```

Answer (score 3):

`include?` block returns `true/false`, try use `select` function to filter illegal characters.

```
result = str.map {|txt| txt.chars.select {|c| alpha_num.include?(c.downcase)}}
            .map {|chars| chars.join('')}

p result
```

Answer (score 0):

```
exclusions = ((32..126).map(&:chr) - [*'a'..'z', *'A'..'Z', *'0'..'9']).join
  #=> " !\"\#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~"

arr = ['He,llo!', 'What Ho!']    

arr.map { |word| word.delete(exclusions) }
  #=> ["Hello", "WhatHo"]
```

If you could use a regular expression and truly only wanted to remove punctuation, you could write the following.

```
arr.map { |word| word.gsub(/[[:punct:]]/, '') }
  #=> ["Hello", "WhatHo"]
```

See [String#delete](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-delete). Note that `arr` is not modified.

Comment: I can't bring myself to naming an array `str`.